# What is the correct syntax to exclude a folder's contents but not the folder itself

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that copies files from `$source` to `$dest` and it excludes some files types. It excludes my csv files and web.config files fine, but it won't exclude the Log folder contents. This is my script, what is the correct syntax to exclude the files contents but not the `Log` folder itself?

```
$exclude = @('Thumbs.db','*-Log.csv','web.config','Logs/*')

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to setup a second Array with the paths you want to avoid and then add a filter in the pipe. Here's some sample code:

```
$exclude = @('Thumbs.db','*-Log.csv','web.config','Logs/*')
$directory = @("C:\logs")
Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | where {$directory -notcontains $_.DirectoryName}
```

Comment: Will that copy the directory but not the files or will it just ignore the entire folder?

Comment: That should copy the folder but not the contents. The where clause only affects files. If you want to limit folders, you have to use "$_.Name" or "$_.FullName" depending on the situation.

Comment: For me that where clause makes no sense, but it works!

Comment: Note that where clause `where {$directory -notcontains $_.DirectoryName}` is subtle ... it is matching the given entry's directoryname property against the list in $directory - meaning that ***exact entries only*** will work this way. If I want to exclude a path component (like bin) there is no method for that unless I list each and every complete path that I want to exclude (i.e. c:\temp\bin, c:\bin, C:\bin\temp)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own recursive copy function.

```
function Copy-WithFilter ($sourcePath, $destPath)
{
    $exclude = @('Thumbs.db', '*-Log.csv','web.config', 'Logs')

    # Call this function again, using the child folders of the current source folder.
    Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Exclude $exclude | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq $null } | % { Copy-WithFilter $_.FullName (Join-Path -Path $destPath -ChildPath $_.Name) } 

    # Create the destination directory, if it does not already exist.
    if (!(Test-Path $destPath)) { New-Item -Path $destPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null }

    # Copy the child files from source to destination.
    Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Exclude $exclude | Where-Object { $_.Length -ne $null } | Copy-Item -Destination $destPath

}

# $source and $dest defined elsewhere.
Copy-WithFilter $source $dest
```