# Copy large number of files but exclude certain sub folders on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8

I want to backup my work folder which is mainly contained within a folder structure such as:

```
www
    - project 1
        - assets
        - node_modules
    - project 1
        - assets
        - node_modules
    - project 1
        - assets
        - node_modules
```

I need to copy all of the projects but exclude the node_modules folder within each project. Is there an easy way to do this in bulk? As I have large quantities of projects to go through.

Running on Windows 8.1

Comment: Look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/359031/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-exclude-a-folders-contents-but-not-the-folder-its . In the question itself is your answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### I need to copy all of the projects but exclude the node_modules folder

You can use `xcopy` together with the `exclude` option:

```
xcopy www backup /exclude:except.txt
```

- `except.txt` contains the list of files of directories to be excluded.

except.txt:

```
node_modules
```

---

> `/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...`
>
> - The files can each contain one or more full or partial pathnames to be excluded.
> - When any of these match any part of the absolute path of a SOURCE file, then that file will be excluded.
> - For example, specifying a string like `\obj\` or `.obj` will exclude all files underneath the directory `obj` or all files with the `.obj` extension respectively.

Source [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: Awesome, thank you I will give this a go. I also found this: `robocopy SOURCE DESTINATION /mir /xd FOLDER_TO_EXCLUDE` — I Assume it could work too?

Comment: Quite likely. I don't know robocopy though :/ Please don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: Give `robocopy` a try - it was designed to support the same command options as `xcopy` but features a lot of improvements - long path support, buffering, unicode, it preserves timestamps etc. etc. `Robocopy` is part of Windows since Vista, installable on XP.

Comment: This command did not copy any subfolder from my source, only files within that folder.

Comment: @DavidPostill Do I seriously have to put the directories I want to exclude in a text file and then reference that text file in the command? Can't I just tell it directly which directories I want to exclude? I guess `robocopy` is better.

Comment: I take my word back, robocopy absolute staggers copying from exFat partition just like explorer GUI. xcopy on the other hand does the job perfectly.

Comment: Superb response!  You'll probably be amused to hear that your solution not only worked like a charm ... but my motivation was the same thing - a stupid, oversized "node_modules" in the middle of the project directory I want to back up frequently.  Thank you!

Answer (score 28):

Thanks to @DavidPostill for his answer. It worked a treat. I did however also managed to get robocopy working. For those whom it might help, the command was:

```
robocopy SOURCE DEST /mir /xd node_modules
```

Source being the folder to copy, and dest being the destination. And right at the end I have node_modules as the folder I want to exclude.

Comment: Good ol' `robocopy /mir`.  Very powerful switch that can do a lot of good, but just be aware of what that switch does before you go using it.  It will sync two dirs, including deleting items if they don't exist in the source dir.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works very well for syncing my Documents folder with Dropbox, but excluding the node_modules folders since they take up so much space

Comment: @AdamPlocher Your comment saved me from data loss. I've been using robocopy as a substitute for moving folders, didn't occur to me it would delete files from the target folder. Thankfully I was able to recover a backup from 4 days ago, so thank you.

Answer (score 9):

In the **contextual menu** of the "*file explorer*" I added a **powershell script** that allows me to **duplicate any folder without node_modules** :

[image]

#### Here's how to do it :

Create your PowerShell script file `script.ps1` :

```
$Source=$args[0]
$Position = $Source.lastindexofany("\")
$Destination = $Source.substring(0, $Position + 1)
$FolderName = $Source.substring($Position + 1)
$Destination = "$($Destination)$($FolderName)-DUPLICATE_WITHOUT_NODE_MODULES"
robocopy $Source $Destination /mir /xd node_modules
```

Create a registry file : (ex: `Add_Script_To_ContextMenu.reg`)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\DupFolderWithoutNodeModules]
@="Duplicate folder without node_modules"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\DupFolderWithoutNodeModules\command]
@="C:\\\\Windows\\\\system32\\\\WindowsPowerShell\\\\v1.0\\\\powershell.exe -File \"C:\\Path of_your_script\\script.ps1\" \"%L\""
```

Replace `C:\\Path of_your_script` by yours.
Do not forget to double `\` by `\\`.

Then, double clic on the .reg file !

And it's done.

Comment: My man you are amazing!!!

Comment: Holy moly! BTW, to use this utility from command line, just add `script.cmd` somewhere in PATH with this content, in my case: `pwsh.exe %USERPROFILE%\cmd\copy_without_node_modules.ps1 %*`